# R iterator example crashes

Tags: r, iterator, package

This seems pretty simple, so I hope I am doing something wrong. I upgraded R and packages, but now I get the following from running the example in the package PDF:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] iterators_1.0.13

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.2   parallel_4.1.2   tools_4.1.2      itertools_0.1-3  rJava_1.0-5     
> library(iterators)
> i1 <- iter(1:3)
> nextElem(i1)
Error: StopIteration
>
```

I didn't see any other posts noting that something in the latest releases was broken, so I don't know where to go from here. Thanks for any help, links or info!

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error in a vanilla R session on my system. The last statement returns `1L`. Can you retry in a vanilla R session? Run `R --vanilla` in Terminal then do `library("iterators"); i1 <- iter(1:3); nextElem(i1)`.

Comment: @MikaelJagan, running with "--vanilla" R works. Out of curiosity, I ran "R" from the Terminal (no "--vanilla") and that worked, too. The same calls fail, however, when run in RStudio. Is this an RStudio problem?

Comment: Well, it could be an interaction with one of the packages you seem to have loaded in RStudio. You could restart your R session in RStudio and try again? If that works, then you could try loading those packages one at a time to see which breaks the code.

Comment: @MikaelJagan I ran invisible(lapply(paste0("package:", names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)),   # Unload add-on packages
+                  detach,
+                  character.only = TRUE, unload = TRUE)) to unload all loaded packages and got the same error.

Comment: It does seem to be a problem with R 4.1.2 interacting with RStudio. I tried several older versions of RStudio and R 4.1.2 and they all failed. I then went back to R 3.3.3 and the error goes away with all of the RStudio versions I tried. I am running Mac OS 11.6 on an Intel Quad core i7.

Comment: R v4.0.x all work. The problem first appears with R v4.1.0. The error occurs for (at least) the broad range of RStudio versions that I tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `iter(1:3)`, R dispatches to the default method `iter.default`, which is defined as:

```r
function (obj, checkFunc = function(...) TRUE, recycle = FALSE, ...) {
  state <- new.env()
  state$i <- 0L
  state$obj <- obj
  n <- length(obj)
  it <- list(state = state, length = n, checkFunc = checkFunc, recycle = recycle)
  class(it) <- c("containeriter", "iter")
  it
}
```

`iter.default` doesn't do anything out of the ordinary that might cause the result to differ between repeated evaluations (e.g., random number generation). This means that `iter(1:3)` should *always* evaluate to a named list containing an environment `state` binding `i = 0L`.

In a vanilla R (4.1.2) session on my system, it does just that:

```r
$ R --vanilla
> library("iterators")
> x <- iter(1:3)
> x$state$i
[1] 0
```

But in RStudio (desktop 1.4.1717):

```r
> library("iterators")
> x <- iter(1:3)
> x$state$i
[1] 4
```

which accounts for the `StopIteration` error thrown by `nextElem`;
see the definition of `nextElem.containeriter` [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/iterators/blob/master/R/iterators.R) (slightly too long to paste).

Running `iter(1:3)` under a debugger, line by line, I determined that the value of `i` in the environment `state` changes from `0L` to `4L` at the line `class(it) <- c("containeriter", "iter")`.

```r
> library("iterators")
> debugonce(iterators:::iter.default)
> iter(1:3)
debugging in: iter.default(1:3)
debug: {
    state <- new.env()
    state$i <- 0L
    state$obj <- obj
    n <- length(obj)
    it <- list(state = state, length = n, checkFunc = checkFunc, 
        recycle = recycle)
    class(it) <- c("containeriter", "iter")
    it
}
Browse[2]> n
debug: state <- new.env()
Browse[2]> n
debug: state$i <- 0L
Browse[2]> n
debug: state$obj <- obj
Browse[2]> n
debug: n <- length(obj)
Browse[2]> n
debug: it <- list(state = state, length = n, checkFunc = checkFunc, 
    recycle = recycle)
Browse[2]> n
debug: class(it) <- c("containeriter", "iter")
Browse[2]> state$i
[1] 0
Browse[2]> n
debug: it
Browse[2]> state$i
[1] 4
Browse[2]>
```

(Here, `n` is an instruction to the debugger to run the **n**ext line, not R code.)

Interestingly, the glitch is avoided when we access the result of `iter(1:3)` without assigning it to a name.

```r
> iter(1:3)$state$i
[1] 0
```

The glitch is *also* avoided when we take away the `iterators` interface altogether.

```r
> f <- function (obj, checkFunc = function(...) TRUE, recycle = FALSE, ...) {
+   state <- new.env()
+   state$i <- 0L
+   state$obj <- obj
+   n <- length(obj)
+   it <- list(state = state, length = n, checkFunc = checkFunc, recycle = recycle)
+   class(it) <- c("containeriter", "iter")
+   it
+ }
> x <- f(1:3)
> x$state$i
[1] 0
```

So, there *seems to be* a corruption of memory, and the cause *seems to be* an interaction between `iterators` and RStudio. It may be worth reporting the issue to RStudio [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues) [edit: I've just done this; see [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10185)] and keeping the `iterators` maintainers in the loop [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/iterators) [edit: I've also done this; see [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/iterators/issues/3)).

FWIW, here are my system details. Not clear yet whether the problem is platform-dependent...

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.6.1
```

#### Update

An RStudio engineer replied to my [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/10185). Below is an elaboration of their response:

By default, RStudio silently calls `str` on objects bound in the global environment, in order to populate the Environment pane with useful information. So, as soon as you assign `x <- iter(1:3)` in the global environment:

1. RStudio silently evaluates `str(x)`.
2. R dispatches to `str.default`.
3. `str.default` evaluates `vapply(x, typeof, "")`.
4. `vapply` evaluates `as.list(x)`.
5. R dispatches to `as.list.iter` (source code [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/iterators/blob/master/R/aslist.R)).
6. `as.list.iter` iterates over all of the elements of `1:3`.

As a result, the value of `x$state$i` ends at one plus the length of `1:3`.

We can reproduce RStudio's behaviour in vanilla R like so:

```
$ R --vanilla
> library("iterators")
> x <- iter(1:3)
> x$state$i
[1] 0
> as.list(x)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

> x$state$i
[1] 4
```

To get around RStudio's auto-`str`, you can set the Environment pane to "Manual Refresh Only". A more permanent fix would require the `iterators` maintainers to write a `str` method for class `"iter"` or refactor their `as.list` method.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough work on this AND for your instructive answer. Thank you, too, for contacting the RStudio folks (I wasn't sure how to do that), finding the cause and finding a work-around. I downloaded R4.1.2, opened RStudio, clicked the circular arrow in the upper right corner of the Environment panel, selected "Manual Refresh Only", re-ran, and now all works as expected. Happy it all works, learned a few things from the process, but mostly impressed with the helpfulness of folks in the R community, like you! Thanks!

Comment: me too after reading this thread posted more than a year ago. the work being done here is remarkable, thumb up & up & up